# Facebook SDK returns nil for user first_name, last_name, email and username in Swift with Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm writing app with Parse and Facebook SDK. I've successfully implemented Parse login and Facebook login and now experience some troubles with retrieving data from Facebook.
I use following code to get data:

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters:nil)
request.startWithCompletionHandler {
   (connection, result, error) in
   if error != nil {
      print (error)
   } else if let userData = result as? NSDictionary {
      print (userData["name"] as? String)
      print (userData["first_name"] as? String)
      print (userData["last_name"] as? String)
      print (userData["email"] as? String)
      print (userData["username"] as? String)
   }
}
```

And as a result I receive this:

```
Optional("Name Surname")
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

First string means that data was successfully received and full name is not empty, but all remaining strings are empty. At the same time I checked my Facebook profile and I have separate name and surname in settings and my e-mail is verified. 
For read permissions I set `["public_profile", "email"]`.
What's wrong here and why do I get nil for all this strings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

send parameters with request like

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name"])
```

Comment: Where is this listed in the Facebook documentation guides ? I don't see this commonly requested function in the getting started guides..